# Fitting data with coupled ODEs using python package "bumps"

Tags: python, ode, data-fitting

I've found online the toolbox bumps (https://pypi.org/project/bumps/) which looks like a well-rounded and easy to use approach to fit data.
I'm interested to fit data described by two coupled ODEs, but, unfortunately, I haven't found any information regarding this procedure on the docs (https://bumps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).
Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `bumps` states to be for inverse problems. Having ODE's and fitting should be a standard thing to solve in Python. Just use `scipy.optimize` with `odeint`.

Answer (score 1):

I've ask to the developer on GitHub and he provided two complete examples.
Here the link: https://github.com/bumps/bumps/issues/26

Comment: ...sure...but why?